# My javascript code result is blinking

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I am clicking on the Bengali button its showing data for few seconds and hiding it again, whereas I wrote the same code for the Assamese button, it displaying fine:

[image]

```
<script>
    function be(){
      var x= document.getElementById('ben');
      if (x.style.display==='block'){
        x.style.display='none';
      }
      else
      {
        x.style.display='block';
      }
    }
</script>
<button class= "button" onclick="be()">BENGALI</button>
<div id="ben">
<?php
$dir = '/home/test/data/Bengali/';
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if ($dp = opendir($dir)) {
    $files = array();
    while (($file = readdir($dp)) !== false) {
        if (!is_dir($dir . $file)) {
            $files[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($dp);
}

if ($files) {
    echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">';
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="' . $file . '" /> ' 
 .
             $file . '<br />';

  }
}
}
?></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You call the function when you click on a submit button.

So the JS runs, then the form submits, and you load a new page.

The new page doesn't set the default styles to what they were before, so it has the effect of resetting the page.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, a new page is opening because a button has been clicked. The best way to solve this is by modifying your button like this:

```
<button class= "button" onclick="be()" type="button">BENGALI</button>
```

This prevents the form from submitting and runs your JavaScript function

Comment: can i put the path name in the text box and give me the following file list.